# Is it possible to suppress the output to terminal before successfully login the telnet?

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I can successfully login the Telnet and run `ls` command by invoking the commands below in bash.

I hope to suppress the output to the terminal before successfully login the telnet?

```
    expect << EOS
        spawn telnet 192.168.1.11
        expect "login:"
        send "root\r"
        expect "#"
        send "ls\r"
        expect "#"
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
EOS
```

Here is the output:

```
spawn telnet 192.168.1.11
Trying 192.168.1.11...
Connected to 192.168.1.11 .
Escape character is '^]'.

Linux (03:04 on Wednesday,)

Ambarella login: root
Last login: Wed Jun  1 02:57:18 from 192.168.1.11   
# ls  #how to suppress the output above?
test        nw  sample
# exit #how to suppress the output below? 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

***UPDATED***:
@wjandrea I carefully read the [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1439586/how-do-i-get-my-expect-statement-to-not-output-the-stdout-of-the-first-command). But it seems not what I expect. There is no output for `ls` either, if I call

```
expect << EOS
        spawn telnet 192.168.1.11
        log_user 0;
        expect "login:"
        send "root\r"
        expect "#"
        send "ls\r"
        expect "#"
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
EOS
```

***UPDATED AGAIN***:
Thanks to @Colin Macleod, @wjandrea and @glenn jackman.
There is still a question left.
I update the script, but I can't suppress `ls`. I don't want to see it indeed.

```
expect << EOS
        log_user 0;
        spawn telnet 192.168.1.11
        expect "login:"
        send "root\r"
        expect "#"
        send "ls\r"
        log_user 1;
        expect "#"
        log_user 0;
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
EOS
```

Here is the output:

```
ls   #how to suppress this line?
test        nw  sample
```

***UPDATE the third time:***

Thanks to @glenn jackman.

I try to suppress the echo to `pwd` which is sent to the remote computer. But it seems that I miss something, it does not work as expected. You see there is no useful message is printed out when `puts "the output:$output"` is invoked.

Here is the script:

```
expect << EOS
        log_user 0;
        spawn telnet 192.168.1.11
        expect "login:"
        send "root\r"
        expect "#"
        
        set prompt "#"
        set command "pwd"
        
        log_user 1;
        send "$command\r"
        expect -re "$command\r\n(.+)\r\n$prompt"

        set output $expect_out(1,string)

        puts "the output:$output"

        send "exit\r"
        log_user 0;
        expect eof
EOS
```

Here is the output, which is seen in the local terminal:

```
                  //this line is empty
# the output:     //there is a space between `#` and `the output`, and the cursor twinkles for several seconds before `the ouput` is printed out. It seems some command(I guess it's `expect`) is waiting for timeout.
```

***What's more***, if I replace  `send "$command\r"` with  `send "pwd\r"`. The code snippet works as **almost** expected.

Here is the code snippet:

```
expect << EOS
        log_user 0;
        spawn telnet 192.168.1.11
        expect "login:"
        send "root\r"
        expect "#"
        
        set prompt "#"
        set command "pwd"  
        
        log_user 1;
        send "pwd\r"      #modification is at here
        expect -re "$command\r\n(.+)\r\n$prompt"

        set output $expect_out(1,string)

        puts "the output:$output"

        send "exit\r"
        log_user 0;
        expect eof
EOS
```

Here is the output:

```
pwd
/root
# the output:   //no valid output, very strange.
```

***And*** I am using

```
 expect -version
expect version 5.45.3
```

Comment: What research have you done? I've never used `expect`, but I googled "expect hide output until login" and this seems to have the answer: [How do I get my expect statement to not output the stdout of the first command? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1439586/443564)

Comment: @wjandrea I searched on Stackoverflow indeed and found nothing useful.I will carefully read the post right now. But it seems not what I expect. There is no output for `ls` either, if I call add `log_user 0;` in the code snippet above. The full code snippet is seen at the session named ***UPDATED***.

Comment: Note that you can use `log_user 1` to turn output back on at the point when you want it.

Comment: And to hush the output from `spawn`, use `spawn -noecho ...`

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you for pointing out that. But I am conscious  about what the output of `spawn` is. Maybe a simple example helps. I googled indeed, but nothing helps.

Comment: @ColinMacleod Thank you for pointing out that! I still face a problem. See the section named `UPDATED AGAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the tricky/aggravating things about expect. What you capture is everything you would see on the screen -- all of the prompt and the command you typed/sent and the command output.

You need to use the `-re` option for the `expect` command to capture the output, and then parse out the command.

You can do something like this:

```
send "ls\r"
expect -re "(.*)#"
regexp {ls\r\n(.+)\r\n} $expect_out(1,string) -> ls_output
```

Note that Expect uses `\r\n` line endings for the data returned from the spawned process

Another option, more general:

```
set prompt "#"

set command "ls -l"
send "$command\r"
expect -re "$command\r\n(.+)\r\n$prompt"

set output $expect_out(1,string)
```

Comment: Thank for the clarification. It's so complicated. :( What's `set output $expect_out(1,string)`?

Comment: A side-effect of the `expect` statement is that the `expect_out` array is populated with various values. The full details are in [the man page.](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=expect&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html) `$expect_out(1,string)` is populated when the `-re` option is used: it holds the text that matched the first set of capturing parentheses. Yes it's complicated, but expect is a very powerful language.

Comment: What is `expect_out`? A variable? Or a command?

Comment: It's an array variable. That syntax is pretty fundamental: you might gain from a pass through [the Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).

Comment: It seems I still miss something. I read the said link carefully, but I can't find out how to make it work as expected. I updated the post. Please see the session named `UPDATED the third time`. Could you please give me a hand?

Comment: Why do you `exit` after the first ls?

Comment: Sorry for my foolishness. I updated it. The session is named as ` the session named UPDATED the third time. `